# Bootstrap modal Hidden under Parent Components

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, parent-child

I am using bootstrap modal in child component in angular 4 , I can see the modal  but It is hidden by parent component . I have increased z-index , nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the z-index with important:

```
z-index: 10001!important;
```

Comment: Thanks pixelbits . It did not work  for me.  Its something related to parent and child components which I am not able to figure out.